# How can I view all system logs at once?

Tags: journalctl

My computer is constantly making the sound of a usb device being un-plugged and plugged in (about once a minute). It's driving me crazy.  I've run `journalctl --follow` as root, but there are no messages corresponding to the sounds.

How can I increase the verbosity of journalctl and have it print messages from all modules to debug what's causing this sound?

Comment: are `dmesg` messages making it to `journald`?  `journalctl -k` shows some stuff?

Comment: Yes, there is output in general. In the past my experience was I got much more detailed output when specifying a single unit than when just running `journalctl` with no flags. Though maybe I'm wrong about that.